# How to return value using $q in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i return data using **promise**
Got error that successdata is not a function in my controller, i don't know what am i doing wrong. Do i miss something in my controller ? 
I observ by debug app response is coming in service but nothing is returning from it

```
 var module = angular.module('app', []);
module.service("webservice", function($http,$q) {

    return {
        callservice:function(method,url,_data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = deferred.promise;
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: App_Service_api+url,
                data: _data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.success) {
                    deferred.resolve(data.message);
                    //return deferred.promise;
                    promise.successdata = function(fn) {
                        promise.then(fn);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
                    //return deferred.promise;
                    promise.errordata = function(fn) {
                        alert("error");
                        promise.then(null, fn);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                }

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
                //return deferred.promise;
                promise.errordata = function(fn) {
                    promise.then(null, fn);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }); 

        }
    }
})
```

**Here is my controller code**

```
webservice.callservice('POST',App_Service_login,inputs).successdata(function(data){
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login Succesfull!',
                    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                });
            })
                .errordata(function(data) {
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Login failed!',
                        template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored a bit your code. Sincerely I didn't understand why you are created the functions `successdata` and `errordata`. You could try something more simple like this:

Service:

```
module.service("webservice", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        callservice: function(method, url, _data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: App_Service_api + url,
                data: _data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                if (data.success) {
                    deferred.resolve(data.message);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
                }
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                deferred.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
            }); 
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
webservice.callservice('POST', App_Service_login, inputs).then(function(dataMessage){
    console.log('dataMessage', dataMessage);
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login Succesfull!',
        template: 'Please check your credentials!'
    });
})
.catch(function(errorMessage) {
    console.log('errorMessage', errorMessage);
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login failed!',
        template: 'Please check your credentials!'
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

This `service` code should be improved with a little fix on the server side returning the [correct http status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). With this change instead of returning the property `data.success = false` when there some validation Errors you should return `Status 400 Bad Request` and `data.message = 'Please Enter valid data'`. Doing so you should remove the property `data.success` from your response, the controller would remain the same, and your service become:

Service:

```
module.service("webservice", function($http, $q) {
    return {
        callservice: function(method, url, _data){
            return $http({
                method: method,
                url: App_Service_api + url,
                data: _data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            });
        }
    }
});
```

From [Angular $http doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that
>   if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently
>   follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such
>   responses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your code right, but I think it is far to complicated.
Simply do:

```
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.success) {
            deferred.resolve(data.message);
        }else{
            deferred.reject(...)
        }
```

and:

```
webservice.callservice('POST',App_Service_login,inputs)
.then(function(data){
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({..})
}, function(err){
  //errorhandling
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$http` itself is returning a promise, so there is no need to create a new deferrable there.

The whole thing can be simplified into:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);
module.service("webservice", function($http,$q) {

    return {
        callservice:function(method,url,_data){
            return $http({
                method: method,
                url: App_Service_api+url,
                data: _data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).
            then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    return data.message;
                }
                else {
                    $q.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
                }
            }, function() {
                $q.reject("Plase Enter valid data.");
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```